# Is it possible to install Windows Server 2008 R2 on a QNAP NAS?

Tags: windows-server, qnap

Is it possible to install windows server 2008 on a QNAP NAS or would I need to build my own server.

Does anyone know any decent resources on building a server computer? I'm very new at this and just want to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature available on QNAP NAS (Intel or AMD based NAS) called Virtualization Station. They have an "on-device hypervisor" built-in which allows you to run multiple virtual machines on QNAP NAS.

You can easily install the Widnows OS including Windnows Server 2008 R2 and run on top of the QNAP storage. If you intend to run performance demanding applications on the Windows server, it is recommended to choose higher end QNAP, e.g. i7 or Xeon CPU with more memory upgraded.

FYI: https://www.qnap.com/event/station/en-us/virtualization.php

Answer (score 0):

You can install Windows on your QNAP NAS as long as it is an Intel based model.
For Atom, Celeron and Pentium based models, you should install at least Windows Server 2012 R2 to take advantage of the built-in power management drivers for Intel based low powered computers.
If preparing a Windows drive on a different computer, there is no need to use EFI deployment instructions, BIOS based deployments will boot on the QNAP EFI firmware, however EFI based deployments using GPT format disks do not.
Hope this helps.